# How do I go about ending this loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to count the longest length of string in alphabetical order

```
s = 'abcv'
longest = 1
current = 1
for i in range (len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        current += 1
    else:
        if current > longest:
            longest = current
            current = 0
    i += 1
print longest
```

For this specific string, 'Current' ends up at the correct length, 4, but never modifies longest.

EDIT: The following code now runs into an error

```
s = 'abcv'
current = 1
biggest = 0
for i in range(len(s) - 1):
    while s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        current += 1
        i += 1
    if current > biggest:
        biggest = current
    current = 0
print biggest
```

It seems my logic is correct , but I run into errors for certain strings. :(

Although code sources are available on the internet which print the longest string, I can't seem to find how to print the longest length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`break` will jump behind the loop (to sam indentation as the `for` statement. `continue` will jump to start of loop and do the next iteration

Your logic in the `else:` statement does not work - you need to indent it one less.

---

```
if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
```

checks for "is actual char less or equal then next char" - if this is the case you need to increment your internal counter and set longest if it is longer

You might get into trouble with `if s[i] <= s[i+1]:` - you are doing it till `len(s)-1`.   `"jfjfjf"` is `len("jfjfjf") = 6` - you would iterate from 0 to 5 - but the if accesses `s[5]` and `s[6]` which is more then there are items.

---

A different approach without going over explicit indexes and split into two responsibilities (get list of alphabetical substring, order them longest first):

```
# split string into list of substrings that internally are alphabetically ordered (<=)
def getAlphabeticalSplits(s):
    result = []
    temp = ""
    for c in s: # just use all characters in s
        # if temp is empty or the last char in it is less/euqal to current char
        if temp == "" or temp[-1] <= c: 
            temp += c # append it to the temp substring
        else:
            result.append(temp) # else add it to the list of substrings
            temp = "" # and clear tem
    # done with all chars, return list of substrings
    return result


# return the splitted list as copy after sorting reverse by length
def SortAlphSplits(sp, rev = True):
    return sorted(sp, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=rev)

splitter = getAlphabeticalSplits("akdsfabcdemfjklmnopqrjdhsgt")
print(splitter)
sortedSplitter = SortAlphSplits(splitter)
print (sortedSplitter)
print(len(sortedSplitter[0]))
```

Output:

```
['ak', 's', 'abcdem', 'jklmnopqr', 'dhs']
['jklmnopqr', 'abcdem', 'dhs', 'ak', 's']
9
```

This one returns the array of splits + sorts them by length descending. In a critical environment this costs more memory then yours as you only cache some numbers whereas the other approach fills lists and copies it into a sorted one.

To solve your codes index problem change your logic slightly:
Start at the second character and test if the one before is less that this. That way you will ever check this char with the one before

```
s = 'abcvabcdefga'
current = 0
biggest = 0
for i in range(1,len(s)): # compares the index[1] with [0] , 2 with 1 etc
    if s[i] >= s[i-1]:    # this char is bigger/equal last char
        current += 1
        biggest = max(current,biggest)
    else: 
        current = 1

print biggest
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you check the code I have edited above. Is there a simpler way of achieving the count? I am quite new and have not been introduced to the syntax in your solution to curb the s[i] error

Comment: read my answer again :) you are running into an index problem because you access the character behind the last one. The error message (which you should always add in as well to your questions edit :o) tells you as much: `IndexError: string index out of range`

Comment: @Sam slight change to your code to fix indexing error

Comment: Thank-you very much! Works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit out the else statement. Because **consider the case** where the current just exceeds longest, i.e, from `current = 3 and longest =3` , current becomes 4 by incrementing itself. **Now here** , you still want it to go inside the `if current > longest` statement

```
s = 'abcv'
longest = 1
current = 1
for i in range (len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        current += 1
    #else:
    if current > longest:
        longest = current
        current = 0
    i += 1
longest = current
print longest
```

Comment: This gives me incorrect outputs
Should be '4' for the string 'abcv'

Comment: `current = 0`should be `current = 1` tomatch the other indexer logic

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the loop, *current* is the length of the last substring in ascending order. Assigning it to *longest* is not right as the last substring in ascending is not necessarily the longest.

So `longest=max(current,longest)` instead of `longest=current` after the loop, should solve it for you.

Edit: ^ was for before the edit. You just need to add `longest=max(current,longest)` after the for loop, for the same reason (the last ascending substring is not considered). Something like this:

```
s = 'abcv'
longest = 1
current = 1
for i in range (len(s) - 1):
    if s[i] <= s[i+1]:
        current += 1
    else:
        if current > longest:
            longest = current
            current = 0
    i += 1
longest=max(current,longest) #extra 
print longest
```

Comment: @PatrickArtner, there was another code block in the question before the edit , and the answer was written wrt that code.

Answer (score 0):

Use a while condition loop, then you can easy define, at what condition your loop is done. 
If you want QualityCode for longterm:
While loop is better practice than a break, because you see the Looping condition at one place. The simple break is often worse to recognize inbetween the loopbody.

Answer (score 0):

The loop ends when there is no code after the tab space so technically your loop has already ended